# Jordan normal form of sum of two commuting nilpotent matrices over a finite field (variant on a linear matrix pencil problem)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras, finite-fields, jordan-normal-form

This question comes up with trying to construct Lie subalgebras of (large) Lie algebras that are invariant under a finite group $H$. I have two isomorphic $H$-invariant nilpotent subalgebras and am interested in the Jordan normal forms of matrices in diagonal subalgebras of these algebras.

I have two commuting nilpotent matrices $A$ and $B$, (dimension 1596, so cannot be just looked at), defined over the field $\mathbb{F}_9$. They both cube to zero, and so $A+\lambda B$ cubes to zero for any $\lambda\in\overline{\mathbb{F}_3}$. I'm interested in the Jordan normal form of the matrix $A+\lambda B$, where $\lambda$ is a parameter.

In all the examples I have so far, if $A$ and $B$ have the same normal form (in the particular case I have in front of me, blocks $3^{285},1^{741}$) then for all but finitely many values of $\lambda$ the blocks of the sum are the same. Furthermore, the number of exceptions to this statement is small, say around $2$.

This could be because my matrices, coming from Lie algebras, are very special. What I really want to know if the following:

- Is it true that $A+\lambda B$ has Jordan normal form independent of $\lambda$ for cofinitely many $\lambda$?
- Is there a bound on the number of exceptions, say in characteristic $3$ with cube zero matrices?
- If $A$ and $B$ are defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$ then do the exceptions lie in a fixed overfield, say $\mathbb{F}_{q^6}$? (I am thinking $6$ because then all quadratics and cubics in $\lambda$ split. I know that one needs at least $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ by examples.)

I really want to know that the JNF of $A+\lambda B$ is what I think it should be for most elements of the algebraic closure, leaving only a finite number to check with a computer. I can do finitely many checks, but not infinitely many! Or is there an algorithm that allows us to understand such problems?

Comment: Something like this is known for modules for elementary abelian $p$-groups in characteristic $p$, a so-called 'generic Jordan type'. For sums of nilpotent rather than products of unipotent matrices, this seems easier. Perhaps a form of linearization would prove the first point, given the statement for elementary abelian groups.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by $3^{285},1^{741}$?

Comment: It has 285 blocks of size 3, 741 of size 1, in its Jordan normal form. So its 0-eigenspace has dimension 285+741, and the matrix has degre 1596. I'm currently looking at what you wrote, and I think I can compute the generic JNF using the ranks of the matrix over a polynomial ring in Magma. The bounds on the extension look a bit worrying for me, since $n=1600$... Hopefully my examples don't need nearly as large an extension. For example, this case, the shared 0-eigenspace between the two matrices has dimension 700-odd, so that can immediately be ignored.

Comment: If $A^3 = 0$, then it should have no blocks of size $3$. Do you mean that $A^4 = 0$? Or, do you mean that these blocks have size $2$?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you count. There are 741 blocks of size $a$, and 285 blocks of size $a+2$. The degree of the matrix is $1596$. So for me the Jordan block $(0)$ has size $1$. It has rank $0$, but as I'm not an official linear algebraist, maybe I use the wrong definition.

Comment: Never mind! I made a very silly mistake. With that said, the last two parts of my answer is incorrect in their current form.

Comment: Sure, I was going to mention it, but I could see what you meant and I was going to wait until I had something more constructive to add. I'm hoping that within this framework I can bring the number of equations needed right down, as otherwise it's a bit impractical with these sizes of matrices.

Comment: I suspect that there is something along the analysis of my third part that can make things more tractable.

Comment: I've edited my answer so that everything is correct. Not quite sure where to go from there. I would recommend that you change bases to put $B$ into the form that I suggest in my answer, and check if the resulting submatrices $A_i$ of $A$ have any interesting structure.

Comment: Also, can $A$ and $B$ have different normal forms? You only refer to the Jordan form $3^{285}1^{741}$ of one matrix, so I suspect you are implying that they are the same

Comment: $A$ and $B$ can have different normal forms, but since their pencil will mostly consist of matrices with the same form, I can choose two with the same form. (I actually care about $\lambda A+\mu B$, but I can of course scale this.) I'm going to have to do this with my examples to see if the space you need is very small, and that it can actually be done.

Comment: One point to keep in mind is that by replacing $\lambda A + \mu B$ with $A + \lambda B$, you lose the $\mu = 0, \lambda = 1$ (i.e. "$\lambda = \infty$") case. If this is a problem, you could consider the pencil
$$
(1 - \lambda) A + \lambda B = A + \lambda(B - A)
$$
instead.

Comment: I don't need to worry about that point because I already know the form there. I am looking for $E_7$ subalgebras of the $C_{28}$ Lie algebra. I know the Jordan normal form of all nilpotent elements of $E_7$, so if a nilpotent element of $C_{28}$ has a form not on that list, my $E_7$ cannot contain it. Thus if I have a finite collection of points I can just compute their forms to make this decision. It's the infinitely many that I have a problem with a priori.

Comment: Have you tried putting $A$ and $B$ into the block-form that I recommend? If you find a pattern, then we might be able to simplify analysis and narrow down the things that can "go wrong" to lead to a deficiency of rank. For instance, we can ignore a number of rows from $A_2 - \lambda I$ corresponding to the rank of $A_1$.

Comment: I haven't done anything yet, I was having lunch. I will have a go today and get back to you. But with the matrices being big I will have to have a play with them as I can never print them out.

Comment: Didn't mean to rush you, sorry if I came off that way. At the very least, the size of $A_1$ is half the rank of $B$, so that's a bit more manageable (but not necessarily printable). Knowing the Jordan form of $A_1$ would be useful, and that doesn't require printing.

Comment: No worries, it's just that because I cannot print the matrix, I need to first work out how the JNF command in Magma orders its rows, then write a script that puts it in that form. Printing out one row of this matrix takes seven lines, even spread out over two monitors.

Comment: Well, I have no experience with Magma so you're on your own there

Comment: I worked out the ordering. It goes block by block, starting with the smallest block. So a permutation matrix will get me into shape. But I need to test it.

Comment: So I can place $B$ into the shape you suggest, that's easy. Now I need to conjugate $A$ into the shape you want. That could take a while.

Comment: So just to clarify things, in case anything is unclear. There are two similarity transformations: the first similarity (applied to both $B$ and $A$) puts $B$ into the block-form below, and because $A,B$ commute it will also put $A$ into the block-form that I give in terms of $A_i$. The second similarity is chosen so that it puts $A_1$ in Jordan form, and is applied to all blocks of $A$ (excluding the last row/column). Applying the same transformation to $B$ should have no effect.

Comment: The Jordan type of $A_1$ is $3^{21},1^{222}$.

Comment: Putting $B$ into that form doesn't make $A$ into exactly that form. It puts zeroes down the lower part of the 3-block matrix, but I can still get non-zero entries outside of that block. In my version, there are non-zero entries in the top-right and in the bottom row, third across. This can be row and columned into the right form, but I currently have only $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$. Although I guess we don't care about $A_4$ if we are just rank counting.

Comment: Sorry, another careless error, it seems. Interesting; still have to figure out where to go from there.

Comment: A point worth considering: if we know that the total number of blocks changes at every exceptional value $\lambda$, then it is sufficient to consider the rank of the pencil $A + \lambda B$. This would necessarily be the case if we knew, for example, that $A + \lambda B$ never has any blocks of size $2$ in its Jordan form.

Comment: It's removed about 1000 dimensions from the problem. It turns out that the rank of $A_3$ is the full $285$. The rank of $A_2$ is $242$. I don't need to know about anything other than the rank, I expect. The 'bad' JNF set is small, and as long as it isn't bad I'm happy, so just getting the rank, even roughly, would probably be enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111411/discussion-between-david-a-craven-and-ben-grossmann).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since found a way to do this, at least in Magma. (Sage should also be able to do it.) Without Ben Grossmann's way of looking at things I definitely would not have thought of doing this, so I thank him. (This is crucial for my research, so I'm very happy!)

Your pencil looks like $A+xB$ for $x$ a variable. Magma (and Sage) is happy to take echelon forms of matrices over a univariate polynomial ring, so let's do that. I've found it might be better to take a Jordan normal form for $B$ first (and of course conjugate $A$) so as to reduce the number of $x$s in the matrix $A+xB$.

Construct the echelon form of $A+xB$. (For $1596 \times 1596$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_9$, this takes about a minute for my examples). Then take transposes and take echelon form again.

We now have a matrix with zero off the leading diagonal. Take the multiset of diagonal entries. First, the generic rank of $A+xB$, i.e., the rank for almost all values of $x$, is the number of non-zero entries. Second, the points where this is not the rank are given by the zeroes of the polynomials in the set.

If one needs the full Jordan normal form, one now takes $(A+xB)^2$ and so on, uses the recipe above to compute the rank, check that the exceptional set should be a subset of the exceptional set for $A+xB$, and continue taking powers until you obtain the zero matrix.

Sage, but not Magma, is happy to compute multivariate echelon forms, which is now my next case. Can this be done with non-linear pencils? The set of exceptions is now a variety, one assumes, and things will get significantly more complicated.

Comment: Well done! I suspect that the result of finding a "two-sided echelon form" of the pencil $A + xB$ is essentially the equivalent of the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of your matrix pencil. I don't know if your methods need any refining or explanation, but if so, then that might be a helpful thing to know.

Comment: Indeed, it should be the SNF. If the underlying ring is a PID it's fine to do this, but in the 2-dimensional case I have to worry that the resulting object might be much more difficult. And I will have to write my own Gaussian elimination algorithm over $F[x,y]$. I'm going to try to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ denote the size of the matrices $A,B$. Note that the Jordan normal form of a size-$n$ matrix $M$ can be completely recovered if one knows the rank of $(M - t I)^k$ for all eigenvalues $t$ of $M$ and $k = 1,2,\dots,n$ (via the "Weyr Characteristic"). In our case, $A + \lambda B$ has $0$ as its lone eigenvalue, so it suffices to consider the rank of $(A + \lambda B)^k$.

For $k = 1,\dots,n$, let $r_k = \max_{\lambda \in \bar{\Bbb F_3}} \operatorname{rank}(A + \lambda B)^k$.  We note that the set $\{M : \operatorname{rank}(M^k) < r_k\}$ is a solution set to a system of polynomials. In particular, it is the set of matrices for which all $r_k \times r_k$ minors are zero.

This is enough for us to deduce that for each $k$, we have $\operatorname{rank}(A + \lambda B)^k = r_k$ for cofinitely many $\lambda$. In particular, the common zero set to a system of polynomials is the same as the zero-set of the product of these polynomials, and a zero-set of a polynomial of one variable must either be the entirety of $\Bbb {\bar F}$ or a finite subset.

Thus, $(A - \lambda B)$ must have constant Jordan form (corresponding to the maximal ranks $r_k$) for cofinitely many $\lambda \in \bar{\Bbb F_3}$.

Moreover, it is possible to obtain a bound on the number of solutions by considering the number and degrees of equations attained by setting the appropriate minors to $0$.

If we know that there are at most $m$ exceptions, then we also know that these exceptions are the zeros of a polynomial with degree at most $m$ and coefficients in $\Bbb F_q$, but this polynomial must split over $\Bbb F_{q^m}$. That is, a positive answer to your second question implies a positive answer to your third.

---

To be a bit more specific: we know that $A + \lambda B$ cubes to zero for all $\lambda$. With that, the only two equations that need to be accounted for are
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A + \lambda B) < r_1, \quad \operatorname{rank}(A + \lambda B)^2 < r_2.
$$
We have $\binom n r^2$ size-$r$ minors, and the entries of $(A + \lambda B)^2$ have at most degree $2$ with respect to $\lambda$. So, the first inequality gives us a system of $\binom n{r_1}$ degree-$r_1$ equations. Similarly, the second inequality gives us a system of $\binom n{r_2}$ degree-$2r_2$ equations.  This is enough to deduce that the solution set in question is necessarily the zero set of some polynomial with degree
$$
m \leq 2\binom n{r_1}\binom n{r_2}r_1r_2.
$$
Note that if $\operatorname{rank}(A + \lambda B) = r_1$, $\operatorname{rank}(A + \lambda B)^2 = r_2$, and $(A + \lambda B)^3 = 0$, then we know that the Jordan form has $n-r_1$ blocks in total, with $r_1 - r_2$ blocks of size at least $2$ and $r_2$ blocks of size at least $3$. Because $(A + \lambda B)^3 = 0$, the Jordan form has no blocks of size $4$ or greater. All together, this gives us $n + r_2 - 2r_1$ blocks of size $1$, $r_1 - 2r_2$ blocks of size $2$, and $r_2$ blocks of size $3$.

If there are no blocks of size $2$, then we have $r_1 = 2r_2$, and $r_2$ blocks of size $3$.

---

We could get a better bound on the number of exceptions as follows. Because $B$ has no blocks of size $2$ we find that (up to similarity over $\Bbb F_q$) $B$ must have the form
$$
B = \pmatrix{0 & I_{k} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & I_{k}\\ 0 &0 &0\\ &&&0},
$$
with $k = \frac 12 \operatorname{rank}(B)$. Because $A$ and $B$ commute, $A$ must have the form
$$
A = \pmatrix{A_1 & A_2 & A_3 & A_{14}\\0 & A_1 & A_2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & A_1 & 0\\ 0&0&A_{43}& A_{44}},
$$
So, that
$$
A + \lambda B = \pmatrix{A_1 & A_2 + \lambda I_{k} & A_3 & A_{14}\\ 0 & A_1 & A_2 + \lambda I_k & 0\\ 0 & 0 & A_1 & 0\\ 
0&0&A_{43}& A_{44}}.
$$
Now, note that the degree of a size $k$ minor for $A + \lambda B$ is at most equal to the minimum of the number of rows and the number of columns selected that correspond to either the $1,2$ or $2,3$ block.

Note that if $SA_1S^{-1}$ is in Jordan form, then we have
$$
\pmatrix{S \\ & S \\ && S\\ &&& I}(A + \lambda B) \pmatrix{S \\ & S \\ && S\\ & &&I}^{-1} = \\
\pmatrix{SA_1S^{-1} & SA_2S^{-1} + \lambda I_{k} & SA_3S^{-1}\\ 0 & SA_1S^{-1} & SA_2S^{-1} + \lambda I_k\\ 0 & 0 & SA_1S^{-1} \\ &&& A_{44}}.
$$
Similarly, we can also put $A_{44}$ into its Jordan form without losing any structure.